# Facebook Ads API (iPhone)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, ads

I want to use Facebook Ads API in my iOS project.

I didn't find any discussion forum, sample etc on Facebook Ads.

Official Facebook Ads API description: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/adsapi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook Ads API lets you create campaigns, ads, ad creatives, as well as get stats on how your ads are performing.  It doesn't render ads inside of an iPhone app or on a 3rd party site.  The Facebook Ads API is only for configuring and manipulating your Facebook ad campaigns for ads that run on facebook.com.  Is this still in line with what you were hoping to do on your iPhone app?

Comment: Yes but i don't need all the feature like create compaign etc. I need only that registered facebook ads user can see their statistics in iphone app with there relevant compaigns

Comment: Tariq - the calls you'll want to make to get this information from Facebook are:
getCampaignStats(account_id) will give you back the stats for the campaigns in this account.
The Facebook Ads API works over HTTP, so as long as your development environment can make HTTP requests, you can use the Facebook Ads API.  Not any application can call the Facebook Ads API at this point in time, since it's in a closed Beta, so your application would have to get approved by Facebook.